# Problems with dataTree

Tags: javascript, tabulator

https://jsfiddle.net/2bav3mkq/1/

1. With `dataTreeStartExpanded=false`, manually expand a tree, and then select Column One on a parent. This collapses the Tree. With `dataTreeStartExpanded=true`, if the Parent is manually collapsed, and then 'ticked' it will expand. It seems to be returning the family to the `dataTreeStartExpanded` status. Either way, Column One should have nothing to do with Tree collapse, that is Column Two's job.
2. Toggling the tick on a child (click in Column One) loses the right-angle graphic. Only way to get it back is to tick the parent.
3. `reactiveData:true` (as set on #expanded) makes no difference ([Is it possible to replace the data in a table that has a data tree without automatically collapsing/expanding the tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909200/is-it-possible-to-replace-the-data-in-a-table-that-has-a-data-tree-without-autom))

Answer (score 0):

The issue was cause by an old bug in Tabulator that resulted in incorrect redawing of the tree elements when the row was updated.

This was resolved in version 4.7.0 so if you update to the latest version of the library everything should work